# Printing Random Values from a JSON File In nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, json

I have a huge json file, containing 75000 Quotes. https://s41.aconvert.com/convert/p3r68-cdx67/uy0lx-j9b81.json. I want to select a random quote and display it in an html file. Im using nodejs, can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I tried looking at https://github.com/tanwanimohit/quotesapi. This. It is very similar to my project except I need to show the quote in an html file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the file locally because the site doesn't allow outside requests.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

function randomIndex(size) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
}

const quotes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("quotes.json", { encoding: "utf-8", flag: "r" }));

const selectedQuote = quotes[randomIndex(quotes.length)];

document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = `"${selectedQuote.QUOTE}" - ${selectedQuote.AUTHOR} (genre: ${selectedQuote.GENRE})`;
```

```html
<span id="quote">Here is where your quote will be</span>
```

Comment: And should I use ejs to link the html and nodejs file?

Comment: AFAIK Node doesn't allow HTML, you'll need to work around that though, my answer was an example. You can't run Node in the browser, I think.

Comment: You can link html and nodejs using a module called ejs. I was referring to that. Thank you for all the help.